# INSERT INTO... SELECT in same table generates foreign key error

Tags: mysql

I am having trouble with the following insert query.

```
INSERT INTO CM_LABEL_CALENDAR (
  label_id,
  label_name,
  order_seq,
  meal_id,
  hyperlink
)
SELECT
  label_id,
  label_name,
  order_seq,
  (meal_id + 315),
  hyperlink
FROM
  CM_LABEL_CALENDAR
WHERE
  (meal_id BETWEEN '1466' AND '1521');
```

When I try to execute it I get the following error:

> Lookup Error - MySQL Database Error: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`TEST_PBMS`.`CM_LABEL_CALENDAR`, CONSTRAINT `CM_LABEL_CALENDAR_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`meal_id`) REFERENCES `CM_MEAL_CALENDAR` (`meal_id`))

I've tried looking for an answer but couldn't find one.

Comment: You should learn about foreign keys. Then you understand the problem and are way better equipped for future SQL usage.

Comment: The error says you have a foreign key problem.  In this case one of the meal_ids you are inserting does not exist in the CM_MEAL_CALENDAR table and it is throwing a fit over it.

Comment: Doing an 'insert into.. select.. ' from the same table is typically a non-starter too..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a foreign key constraint between `CM_LABEL_CALENDAR(meal_id)` and `CM_MEAL_CALENDAR(meal_id)`

You are getting this error because you are trying to insert values in the `meal_id` column that do not exist in the `CM_MEAL_CALENDAR` table.